# Nodemailer contact form works locally but gives an error in deployment

Tags: node.js, forms, heroku, nodemailer

I created a contact form to learn to use nodemailer and in my localhost it works, but after deploying it to Heroku, each time it gives me this error: `{"code":"EAUTH","command":"API"}`

Here is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Middlewares
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); 
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('index.html');
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: process.env.MAIL_USER,
            pass: process.env.MAIL_PASS
        }
    });

    const mailOptions = {
        from: req.body.email,
        to: process.env.MAIL_USER,
        subject: `Message from ${req.body.name}`,
        text: `
        from: ${req.body.name} 
        email: ${req.body.email}
        ${req.body.message}`
    }

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.send(error);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
            res.send('success');
        }
    })
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`server at port ${PORT}`);
});
```

This is the link to the website: https://nodejs-contactform.herokuapp.com/

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure, that your heroku environment has required variables?

Comment: Not sure at all. How do I check that? I'm pretty new to Heroku and deployment stuff.